# Why map is not a function when trying bind data to mui-select component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, drop-down-menu

Trying to populate the `MUI select` component but get the `map is not a function`.
Data structure looks like:

```
export type Airport = {
    iata: string,
    en: string    
}

export type Airports = Airport[];
```

method that calling API looks like:

```
async function getAirports() {
    const { data, status } = await axios.get<Airports>('/Dictionary/GetAirports');
    return data;
}

export const DictionaryService = {
    getAirports
};
```

In console.log I see the required data...

```
const [stationList,setStationList] = React.useState<Airports>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await DictionaryService.getAirports();
                console.log(response);
                setStationList(response);
            } catch (err) {

                console.log(err);
            } 
        };
        getData();
    }, []);
```

Data binding to a component looks like:

```
                    <Select
                        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
                        onChange={handleChangeStation}>
                        <MenuItem defaultChecked={true} value={'*'}><em>ALL</em></MenuItem>
                        {stationList.map(({iata, en}) => { return (
                            <MenuItem key={iata} value={iata}>
                                {en}
                            </MenuItem>
                        )})}
                    </Select>
```

Response from API looks like:

```
{
    "airports": [
        {
            "iata": "wqeq",
            "en": "asdasdad"
        },
        {
            "iata": "qweqw",
            "en": "ssdasdasd"
        }
}
```

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Does `console.log(response);` show that you really have an array? Because it seems like you don't.

Comment: ^ Yeah. Most likely you're receiving a JSON object, and the array is in some property like `data` or what have you. You'll need to set the array value explicitly.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for answer. Please see, i added json example that gets from API.

Comment: @user6408649 as you can see, it's an object, not an array. The property `airports` has a value which is an array.